# Android recyclerview view holder's internal view's animations

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am using an [expandable recycler view](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) and I am trying to make a rotation animation on an ImageView that is a child of the ViewHolder. I set a click listener on the a certain button and in there I call the animateIconExpansion method that performs the animation:

```
private void animateIconExpansion(ImageView expandIcon, boolean isExpanded) {
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.expandIcon, "rotation", rotationEnd - 180f, rotationEnd);
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.start();
    }
```

The problem is that the animation doesn't work properly. I tried using the animate API introduced in 3.0 and it didn't work. I also tried the RotateAnimation and it didn't work:

```
 RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(rotationEnd - 180f, rotationEnd,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotateAnim.setDuration(200);
        rotateAnim.setFillBefore(true);
        expandIcon.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: @kise I have answered my question. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem I was having is that I was making the animation in Adapter. Which was stated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imsr8NrIAMs) as a wrong approach.

What we want to do in this case is to create a class that extends DefaultItemAnimator, override the animateChange method and place your custom animation there.

Now the problem with that is that you don't know the state of your view holder. Sometimes you want to animate the holder when a button is clicked. To solve that you can use flags in your view holder, that you will have a reference to in the animateChange method.

Then you'd want to call recyclerView.setItemAnimator(animater) and pass in an instance of your class.

Comment: Thanks, though I went with the other approach I think this will work.